# Getting GroupNotEmptyException when trying to delete a consumer group in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I executed

```
"kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list"
```

and this results in one group being displayed: console-consumer-961

I then tried to delete this group:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --delete --group console-consumer-961
```

But this results in an exception:

```
Error: Deletion of some consumer groups failed:
* Group 'console-consumer-961' could not be deleted due to: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupNotEmptyException: The group is not empty.
```

I guess this group was created when I ran kafka-`console-consumer.bat`, but now this consumer is not running. How can I delete this consumer group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can validate the state of a consumer group by using the `kafka-consumer-groups` command line tool.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group console-consumer-961 --state
```

This will show you the state of the consumer. If it is not empty, Kafka will not allow to delete that group. If it still shows that your console consumer is running you need to make sure to properly shut it down (usually by CTRL+C)

Comment: I executed the command above and got the group in state Stable - although no consumer was running and the computer was after a reboot. I rebooted the machine again, relaunched zookeeper and kafka and executed the command again. The state changed to Empty! I executed the group delete command again, and this time the command executed successfully.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that if your consumer died suddenly, it might be a ghost member for up to however long your timeout is.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a topic, offset information is now correctly reset. So when you create a topic with the same name, consumers start from the beginning of the new data.

you still can't delete new style consumer groups with the Kafka-consumer-groups tool, but your underlying issue is solved.

Before Kafka 0.10.2, there were hacks, but no clean solution to this issue.